# How to redraw FullCalendar view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I know how to initilize the view of FullCalendar, in particular when my page is load I do:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        'defaultView': 'multiColAgendaWeek',
        'height': BackendCalendar.getCalendarHeight(),
        'editable': true,
        'firstDay': 1, // Monday
        'slotMinutes': 30,
        'snapMinutes': 15,
        'axisFormat': 'HH:mm',
        'timeFormat': 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm}',
        'allDayText': EALang['all_day'], 
        'columnFormat': 
        {
            'month': 'ddd',
            'week': 'ddd D',
            'day': 'dddd'
        },
        'titleFormat': 
        {
            'month': 'MMMM YYYY',
            'week': "MMM D YYYY",
            'day': 'MMMM D YYYY'
        },
        'header': 
        {
            'left': 'prev,next today',
            'center': 'title',
            'right': 'multiColAgendaDay,multiColAgendaWeek,month'
        },
        'views':
        {
            'multiColAgendaDay':
            {
                'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                'duration': { days: 1},
                'columns': 
                [
                    { id:1, name: 'Op1' },
                    { id:2, name: 'Op2' }
                ]
            },
            'multiColAgendaWeek': 
            {
                'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                'duration': { weeks: 1 },
                'columns': [
                    { id: 1, name: 'Op1' },
                    { id: 2, name: 'Op2' }
                ]
            }
        },
```

I'm using this extension: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns/issues/1 that add the resource support. Anyway, What I'm trying to do is change the columns parameter content through code. The `columns` property is inside the two available view `multiColAgendaDay` and `multiColAgendaWeek`. I've a method that's populate the calendar with all the appointments available, this method doesn't reload the page 'cause use an ajax request. All working fine, but I want to add in this method a redraw of the columns available, in particular inside the population method at the top of all redrawing the calendar view:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            views: 
            {
                'multiColAgendaDay': 
                {
                    'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                    'duration': { days: 1 },
                    'columns': 
                    [
                        { id: 1, name: 'First Column' },
                        { id: 2, name: 'Second Column' }
                    ]
                }
            },
            'multiColAgendaWeek': 
            {
                'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                'duration': { weeks: 1 },
                'columns': 
                [
                    { id: 1, name: 'First Column' },
                    { id: 2, name: 'Second Column' }
                ]
            }
        });
```

The problem's that the calendar isn't redrawed and after this code execution the result is ever like this:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe the calendar can't redraw the view without a page reload? How I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly redrawing using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render')`?

Comment: No I doesn't tried with render

Comment: So does `render` work?

Comment: For the moment I've solved setting my operators in the initialization of calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some case render will not works. I have problem such like that so i made a separate method for this. In my case i have passed Json Array on each refresh so, i have first call the method to get array and then add this line:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('destroy');
```

and then create calendar instance and passed Json array to events.